# How to fetch artifacts from all instances of previous job in go-cd?

Tags: parallel-processing, continuous-deployment, go-cd

I have a multistage Go_CD pipeline.  On stage **Stage1** the pipeline runs multiple instances of job '**jobA**'.  Each instance produces an artifact.   On stage 2 '**Stage2**' I want to collect all artifacts from all the instances of **Stage1/JobA**.   But, I can't figure out how.  If I try to fetch artifact from stage1/jobA GO doesn't find anything.  If I specify specific instance of the job like  '**JobA-RunInstnace1**',  '**JobA-RunInstnace2**, ''**JobA-RunInstnace3**' and so on.

Unfortunately I have about 30 of parallel instances of 'JOBA' and configuring Fetch artifact job for every one of them is very tedious.  Is there a better way to tell go that I want to fetch artifacts from all instances of previous job?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider writing a collector script that runs as the first stage of Stage2? The way to access artifacts directly from the Go server is probably via http(s) using the URLs of the artifacts. curl.

Otherwise you could script the generation of the fragments of config.xml for fetching the 30 artifacts... In the latest versions you can import sections of config.xml from outside of GoCD. See [Config Repo Extension](https://docs.gocd.io/current/extension_points/configrepo_extension.html) But that's embarrassingly complicated.

Comment: Collector script needs to know how many instances were run on stage 1.  But bigger problem is that you can't easily fetch artifacts directly from go server using curl because of authentication.  I did cobble up a script that generates XML files,  but it just feels ugly to have to jump through the hoops for such simple thing.